# SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mygmailpassword';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('mygmail@gmail.com', 'Courses');
    $mail->addAddress('mygmail@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@example.com', 'No-reply');
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

This is the error I got

```
2020-05-06 07:59:56 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-05-06 07:59:56 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I changed the port to 465 to 587 but it didn't work. I searched this exact problem but mostly the answer is the port changed to 465 but it didn't work. What I did wrong in the code.Sorry I'm Beginner

Answer (score 1):

Try and add this. This solved the problem for me!

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Make sure you don't have two-step verification switched on

It's worth noting that some SMTP servers block connections. Some SMTP servers don't support SSL (or TLS) connections.

Comment: 2020-05-06 08:32:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP r78sm1134798pgr.40 - gsmtp
2020-05-06 08:32:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2020-05-06 08:32:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2001:4450:832b:8a00:7849:794b:53f9:687]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

Comment: please take a look at this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: This is the correct answer, and that output is debug feedback (which you can turn off), not an error.